# how to bind multiple variables to a variable on an efficient way

Tags: php

I have  to bind multiple variables to another variable ( $products_output)
Now i do it like this:

```
$products_output  = $product1_output;
$products_output .= $product2_output;
$products_output .= $product3_output;
$products_output .= $product4_output;
$products_output .= $product5_output;
// and so on till 50...
```

Is there a way i can do it more efficient then this?
I need the variable **$products_output** in a mail function later and this variable should contain all the variables **$product1_output** till **$product50_output**

**Update:** more info about this question:
I am reading the values with $_POST form a form like this:

```
$product1_output = '';
if(!empty($_POST['product1'])) {
$product1_output =    $product1.'&nbsp;'.$_POST['product1'].'&nbsp;pieces&nbsp;Price&nbsp;&euro;&nbsp;'.number_format($_POST['product1']*$price[$product1], 2);
}
$product2_output = '';
if(!empty($_POST['product2'])) {
$product2_output = $product2.'&nbsp;'.$_POST['product2'].'&nbsp;pieces&nbsp;Price&nbsp;&euro;&nbsp;'.number_format($_POST['product2']*$price[$product2], 2);
}
// and so on...
```

For using all those variables in a mail function, i thougth: bind them all together to just 1 variable like this:

```
$products_output  = $product1_output;
$products_output .= $product2_output;
// and so on...
```

So my question: lets say there a 500 products, each with different prices that i have to read fro the form and multiply with the price of the product, how can i do this in an efficient way without typing long lists of code?

This is piece of the form:

```
 <tr>
            <td><?php echo $product1 ?></td>
            <td>&euro; <?php echo number_format($prijs[$product1], 2); ?></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="product1" size="3" /></td>

        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $product2 ?></td>
            <td>&euro; <?php echo number_format($prijs[$product2], 2); ?></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="product2" size="3" /></td>
        </tr>
```

And i use this  associative array with the list of products.

```
$product1 = 'Broodje Ham';
$product2 = 'Broodje Kaas';
$product3 = 'Broodje Gezond';
$product4 = 'Broodje Tonijn';
$product5 = 'Broodje Zalm';
// and so on...

//prices of products
$price = array(
                $product1 => 3.5, // prijs 3.50 
                $product2 => 3.5,
                $product3 => 3.5,
                $product4 => 4.5,
                $product5 => 4.5,
                // and so on...
 );
```

Comment: Please supply more information.

Comment: Where does your info come from? where does it go?

Comment: You should include more information for readers please.

Comment: You should not worry about efficiency at this level, it would be insignificant.

Comment: It's amazing the quantity of copy + paste on the answers bellow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `${}` is a way to create dynamic variables:

```
for($i=1;$i<=50;$i++){
$products_output .= ${"product".$i."_output"};
}
```

[DEMO](http://ideone.com/OHPrs8)

Comment: This works really great! I did also put a break behind it and now all the echos are neatly displayed under each other: `$products_output .= ${"product".$i."_output"}.'<br />';`

Comment: @nuetmaessen This really isn't the right approach, even if it does work.  You should be using an array, not 50 different variables.

Comment: @Devon, I agree but the SO may need this for a particular reason that I'm not aware of, thank you for pointing that.

Comment: Ok. But the problem with the array is, i still have a long list of code. Lets say, there are 500 products. So i was thinking about the most efficient way to do it without typing too much code

Comment: @nuetmaessen where do you have a long list of code?  You shouldn't if you're creating the array properly.  The array should be created in place of the 500 different variables, not afterwards.

Comment: @Devon Can you give me an example of creating this array?

Comment: @nuetmaessen Update your question with where the 500 different variables are coming from and I will (How $product1_output, $product2_output, and so on are created)

Answer (score 1):

You can write your code as follows.

```
$products_output = "";

for($i=1;$i<=50;$i++){

$prodVar = "product".$i."_output";

$products_output .= $$prodVar;

}
echo $products_output;
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try to source your variables from an array, so the `$products_output` should be an array containing all of the values.

One, you can use brackets in the form input names to start off with an array:

```
<input type="text" name="product[1]" size="3" />
```

So now you will have an array at `$_POST['product']` rather than ~50 different variables.

You can then loop through this array to create an output array using the same key (1...50).

```
foreach ($_POST['product'] as $key => $product) {
  $products_output[$key] = "...";
}
```

Now when you need to use the output array, you can loop through that.

```
foreach ($products_output as $product) {
  echo $product."\n";
}
```

Comment: Ok i see. But what do i have to put inbetween "..."; ?

Comment: The equivalent of what you were setting the `$product#_output` to.  In the foreach loop, `$key` is the #, `$product` is the value of the form input.

Comment: What don't you understand?  Instead of `$_POST['product1']` you have `$_POST['product'][1]`.  You loop through `$_POST['product']` to get `1` as the key, and the value.  You no longer have to individually set each `$product#_output`, you do it in a loop.

Comment: If you still don't understand, you should probably do some reading at php.net about arrays and the foreach control structure.  These are very important to programming, so they are necessary to understand before you can produce quality code.

Comment: yes i think i have to do that first because i do not know what tp put inbetween "..."

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75658/discussion-between-nuet-maessen-and-devon).

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
$products_output = '';
for($i = 1; $i<=50;$i++) {
    $prodx_output = 'product'.$i.'_output';
    $products_output .= $$prodx_output;
 }
```

Comment: It should be `$products_output .= $prodx_output;` or I am mistaken?

Comment: You are mistaken. Run it, limit it and check if var exists... should work.

Comment: @KeepCoding nope, double dollar sign is not a mistake. It denotes [this](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php)

Comment: @JorgeFerreira is there any advantage of using `$$prodx_output` since both `$$prodx_output` and `$prodx_output` producing same output?

Comment: $$prodx_output will not return the same as $prodx_output. the ideia behind it will be to get the value of the variable whose name is in $prodx_output. if you do an echo of both, you'll see one has the variable name, another has the other (your) variable value.

Answer (score 0):

you are looking for [array](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array.php)

Example:

```
$products_output[1] = $product1_output;
$products_output[2] = $product2_output;
```

..

if you want to concate all value from array, you can use  [implode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php)

if you want to parse each variable into array you can use loop [for](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.for.php)

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this

```
$var_prefix = 'products';
$var_suffix = '_output';
$var_name = '';
for($i=1; $i<=50; $i++)
{
    $var_name = $var_prefix.$i.$var_suffix;
    $products_output .= $$var_name;
}
```

It uses [variables variable](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php), but you really should avoid this in your code. Presence of variables `$products1_output`, `$products2_output, ..., $products50_output` indicates, that there are some design problems in your code. You might want to use arrays instead of maintining a bunch of variables with similar names.

[**Demo**](https://ideone.com/L1ZS27)